# Using dark mode for linux GUI apps under WSL 2

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, dark-mode

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 under WSL 2 and GUI apps are working quite well via VcXsrv except that they don't respect the Windows 10 dark mode setting.  I have dark mode on all the time so I'm fine with just having it always use dark mode for linux apps.  I'd much prefer to use linux apps when possible but I also really like using the dark theme.

I've tried the steps suggested in [this AskUbuntu question page](https://askubuntu.com/questions/769417/how-to-change-global-dark-theme-on-and-off-through-terminal), but that doesn't appear to have worked.

Specifically: I created a `settings.ini` in both `~/.config/gtk-3.0` and `~/.config/gtk-4.0` containing the recommended setting.

I've also executed `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface gtk-theme 'Adwaita-dark'.`

I restarted all of my GUI apps but they still are still using the normal light theming.

Is it possible to have linux GUI apps use dark theming under WSL 2?

Answer (score 1):

To solve this issue I am using an app from the Microsoft Store (free) that is called GWSL, it basically creates the Xserver on its own and exports it.
So after installing it you can open any GUI Ubuntu application from the terminal.
Then you can modify the appearance under:
GWSL Distro Tools -> GTK Theme

GWSL Options:
[image: GWSL Options]

Tilix terminal:
[image: Tilix terminal]

Nautilus:
[image: Nautilus]

Comment: is this working for win 11 ? what about QT ?

Comment: It's no longer free except as a trial. Costs $4.99.